# Why is my http post returning null from my view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

This is my model:

```
public class Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
```

I fill it in my GET create

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var Attributes = new[] 
        {
            new Attribute {Key = "Name" Value = "" },
            new Attribute {Key = "Age" Value = "" },
        };
        return View(Attributes);
    }
```

My View looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Customers.ViewModels.Attribute>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label(item.Key)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => item.Value)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Value)
            </div>
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Then My Post Create looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
    }
```

but my `IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes` is null.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your GET is returning Attributes not Attribute

Comment: Yes it is, it's suppose to

Comment: Okay, I see your expecting an IEnumerable<>, my fault, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a editor template for a `Attribute` and then pass the `List<Attribute>` model to  it.

```
@Model Attribute
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Key)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Value)
</div>
```

In your view use:

```
<fieldset>
    @Html.EditorFor(m > m)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

You need to do this because the `foreach` doesn't create the correct name for the elements.

Comment: This works but can you explain to me why I had to do that a little more? I still haven't quite grasped it.

Comment: Also if I have a value in my model that I do not use on the view, I just maybe use it for logic, how can I retain its value on a post?

Comment: When you pass a List of objects, your html elements's name must have this format 'Attribute[0].Property'. If you check your html you'll note that foreach doesn't render as it.

Comment: If you do not use in html, you can't get it on post.

Comment: I could put it in a hidden as I've read but people have been saying that it's a bad idea, is there a better way?

Comment: If it's a critic data you better not put in view as a hidden. I think the best way is to load again the data in your POST.

Comment: The problem with loading it again is that if somehow it does not come back to me in the right order, I will load the data in the wrong places.  So let's say I have that same model but with an ID that I don't want the client to modify, I won't put it in a postback object but when I do postback I can load the IEnumerable list again with my previous Id's but what if the postback somehow did not give me this list in the same order as I had it before